# Add custom column header names to exported Excel file from SQL result

Tags: asp.net

I am using the following code to export to an Excel file.

```
Protected Sub ExportExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT date_bs as date_bs,mt_bs as amount,client FROM tbl_p_exp")

            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    Using wb As New XLWorkbook()
                        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers")

                        Response.Clear()
                        Response.Buffer = True
                        Response.Charset = ""
                        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.xlsx")
                        Using MyMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
                            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
                            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
                            Response.Flush()
                            Response.End()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I need to add specific column names to the exported Excel file.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to change column aliases in your SQL query. Something like this `SELECT date_bs as [operation date], mt_bs as [total amount]...`

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Kudrayshev mentioned in the comments you can alter the column names directly in the query.

```
SELECT column AS [New Column Name]
```

However since you are using DataTables, you can rename the columns there also.

```
dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "New Column Name";
```